# WPF - Grid that must be a part of Page

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, button, grid

Now I've a problem , because I want to create a number of pages that I want populate with a `Grid` and into the `Grid`. I want to create a series of `Button`.

How can I create a `Grid` into a `Page`?

I'm tried with following code:

```
SortedList<string, Page> pageList = new SortedList<string, Page>();

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    pageList.Add(string.Format("Page{0}", i), new Page());
}

Grid LayoutRoot = new Grid(); // ???????
```

What I can do to insert a `Grid` into a `Page`? I want that refer to `Grid` for example:

```
pageList["Page2"].LayoutRoot;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are trying to do. What does your xaml look like? I assume you are using the MVVM pattern, could you show more of your ViewModel as wel? Basically, you have to bind the grid in your xaml(View) to a property in your viewmodel.

Comment: Can you help me to associate the grid to a page using visual c#??

Comment: Do you wanna create dynamically pages so that each page has a grid?

Or do you have predefined pages in which each page has a grid?
Please provide more information

Comment: i want dinamically create a pages!

Comment: You mean like `somePage.Children.Add(new Grid());`?

Comment: I'm resolved with: Grid grid=new Grid; page.content=grid;